# How to read images from inputstream

Tags: android, remote-desktop

Actually i am trying to acheive remote access to computer from android for that i have server in java in which i am doing something like this

```
 public class ScreenCapture
{

private Dimension screensize;
private BufferedImage bi;
private ByteArrayOutputStream byteout;
private byte[] data;

public ScreenCapture() throws IOException, AWTException
{
    screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    bi = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, screensize.width, screensize.height));
    byteout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpeg", byteout);
    data = byteout.toByteArray();
}

public byte[] getScreenCapture()
{
    return data;
}


 }
```

and then we have a Server

```
 public class Server
{
private Connection con;
private ScreenCapture sp;
private Socket soc;
private DataOutputStream out;

public Server() throws IOException, AWTException
{
    con = new Connection();
    sp = new ScreenCapture();
}

public void init() throws IOException

{
    con.setPort(3838);
    soc = con.openConnection();
    out.write(sp.getScreenCapture());
}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{


}
```

}

Client is android-base and code is like and it's not completed i mean i don't know how to fetch images

```
  public class Client extends Activity
{
private DataInputStream input;
private Socket soc;
private Connection con;
private Canvas can;

public void init() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    con.setHost("10.0.2.2");
    con.setPort(3838);
    soc = con.openConnection();
    input.read();
    BitmapFactory b = b.decodeStream(input.readByte());
}
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.androidclientview);     

}

 }
```

So please help me in this, how to display those images, capturing on the servers side